# Why is FindRoot so slow for this problem Det[M[x]]==0

Tags: equation-solving, numerics

I'm trying to use Mathematica to find the numerical solution to an equation `Det[M[x]] == 0`, where `M[x]` is a matrix function of `x`, defined below:

```
r = 10; ω = E^(π I/r); 
M[x_] = Table[D[Cos[ω^j x], {x, i}], {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, 0, r - 1}]; 
G[x_] := Det[N[M[x]]];
M[x] // MatrixForm
```

I expect to see the solution to `G[x] == 0` for large `r` up to a few hundreds, but when I call the function `FindRoot`, it is already very slow even for `r = 10` (doesn't finish in a few seconds):

```
FindRoot[G[x] == 0, {x, (r + 1)/4 π}]
```

But the plot of `G[x]` is extremely fast:

```
Plot[Norm[G[x]], {x, (r + 0.6)/4 π, (r + 0.7)/4 π}]
```

And actually, I tried manually using bisection method and plotting over and over again (each time decreasing the interval by a factor of 2), which give me a very accurate solution in just a minute or so, much faster than `FindRoot`.

So, why is `FindRoot` so slow in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you're using `Det` to detect if the matrix is singular. Determinants are very messy and erratic functions and are generally not a very good measure for how close a matrix is to being singular. That's why `FindRoot` struggles. Instead, you can search for a matrix for which the least singular value is smallest:

```
ClearAll[M, G1, G2]
r = 10;
ω = E^(\[Pi] I/r);
M[x_] = Table[D[Cos[ω^j x], {x, i}], {i, 0, r - 1}, {j, 0, r - 1}];
G1[x_?NumericQ] := Det[M[x]];
G2[x_?NumericQ] := First @ SingularValueList[M[x], -1];

sol = NMinimize[G2[x], x, WorkingPrecision -> 50]
```

> {0, {x -> 0.46507640237572384522369322963792665762298255262859}}

Check solution:

```
N @ G1[x /. Last[sol]]
```

> 2.4946*10^-40 + 3.6561*10^-90 I

**Edit**
I just noticed that I left the `N` function inside of `G2`, which is probably not a good idea. Also, you can use `FindMinimum` instead of `NMinimize` to get your answer a little faster. It's not unique, obviously.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm also interested in the null vector of M[x] at the point where it is singular. I tried NullSpace[M[x0]] (where x0 is the solution to the equation G[x]==0), but it gives nothing, probably because numerical solution is only approximate. So is there an easy way to find this null vector by slightly modifying your code?

Comment: @Lagrenge I'd have to think about that for a bit, but you probably want to read up on `SingularValueDecomposition`. That sounds more or less like what you would need, I think, though I'd have to piece together the details for myself as well. I also believe that `NullSpace` has a `Tolerance` option. You may want to try that as well.

Comment: @Lagrenge This answer might be of use to you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1771013/null-space-from-svd#2286578

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[G];
G[x_?NumericQ] := Det[N[M[x]]]
```

Then [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot) is not too slow:

```
FindRoot[G[x] == 0, {x, (r+1)/4 Pi}] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
>
> {0.017618, {x -> 8.44175 + 5.15677*10^-13 I}}

Comment: It seems like the `FindRoot`'s result is a very poor solution though, using those numbers `G[x]` returns `-196217.-147916 I`. `WorkingPrecision` doesn't improve the accuracy either.

Comment: It seems accuracy improves significantly if the call to `N` is removed from `G[x]`'s definition. I would think it's redundant once `?NumericQ` is applied anyways.

Comment: @eyorble It is not redundant if `Det` and `N` are far from commuting. I have not checked for this example but it would not surprise me, especially if either of `Det` or `FindRoot` is using `Expand`.